# why am i getting this error ? angular.js:13920 Error: [orderBy:notarray]

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I am getting this error message:

[image]

I have no idea where I am going wrong, I have researched bt cannot find the answer for the life of me. I have read documentation to no avail, any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code where the problem is at, I also attached image of error in console.

```
tr ng-repeat="n in list_data| orderBy:Stlc_id|filter:search track by $index">

    <!--<td>{{n.participant_id}}</td>-->
    <td>{{n.First_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Last_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Stlc_id}}</td>

    <td>{{n.Function}}<form action="<?php echo site_url("index.php/transport/get_data")?>" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{n.participant_id}}"><br>
   <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true">  </span>
   </button>  
</form><form action="<?php echo site_url("index.php/transport/edit_data")?>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{n.participant_id}}"><br>
  <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
  </button>  
 </form></td>
    <td>{{n.Attendance_Monday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Attendance_Tuesday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Attendance_Wednesday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Attendance_Thursday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Attendance_Friday}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Lanyard_Status}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Monday_Pick_Up}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Monday_Drop_Off}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Tuesday_Pick_Up}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Tuesday_Drop_Off}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Wednesday_Pick_Up}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Wednesday_Drop_Off}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Thursday_Pick_Up}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Thursday_Drop_Off}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Friday_Pick_Up}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Friday_Drop_Off}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Saturday_Pick_Up}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Saturday_Drop_Off}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Sunday_Pick_Up}}</td>
    <td>{{n.Sunday_Drop_Off}}</td>


</tr>
```

Comment: Try putting quotes around `Stlc_id`: `orderBy:'Stlc_id'`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i tried that and i am still getting same error.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your list_data? From looking at your screenshot, your data is not an array of similar data, so it's unable to sort by a non-existent column.

Comment: Hey Aynber, thanks for responding, as far as i can tell the fields are correct i am getting my data from 3 tables in mysql database.

Comment: How do you get your data, via ajax? Is `list_data` variable initialized at the time of script execution?

Comment: There is an [article](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/orderBy/notarray) in the docs that describes when this error occurs and how to avoid it.

Comment: i get it through ajax

Comment: Please, make sure `list_data` is initialized as empty array before you receive real data from the server. Also, take a look at the article I provided above.